# ¿Como insertar las imagenes que extraigo de mysql en un slider html?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Aguien podria orientarme de como podria colocar las imagenes que extraigo de mi base de datos que estan en mysql e irlas colocando en un slider para que se muestren una por una en el slider, agrego parte de mi codigo donde extraigo las imagenes (las imagenes las guardo en una carpeta y en la base de datos guardo las direcciones de las imagenes), y agrego un slider simple en html pero no he podido mostrarlas bien.

```
        $result_carrusel = "SELECT id, imagen FROM registros ";
        $resultado_carrusel = mysqli_query($connection, $result_carrusel);


        $cont_slide = 0;

        while( $row_slide = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_carrusel))
        {
          $active = "";
          if($cont_slide == 0){
            $active = "active";
          }

       echo $row_slide["id"],"<br>";
          echo '<img src="imagenes/'.$row_slide["imagen"].'"width="100" height="100">';

          $cont_slide++;
        }
```

?>

Este es mi codigo donde muestro un simple slider en html.

```
    <body>
<div id="c-slider">
    <div id="slider">
        <section class="slider_section"><img src="imagen/foto1.jpg" alt="" class="slider_img"></section>
        <section class="slider_section"><img src="imagen/foto2.jpg" alt="" class="slider_img"></section>
        <section class="slider_section"><img src="imagen/foto3.bmp" alt="" class="slider_img"></section>
        <section class="slider_section"><img src="imagen/foto4.jpg" alt="" class="slider_img"></section>

        <!--section class="slider_section"><img src="imagen/foto5.jpg" alt="" class="slider_img"></section-->
        <div id="btn-prev">&#60</div>
        <div id="btn-next">&#62</div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slider.js"></script>
```

'

Comment: Quizá no estas generando la ruta correcta en el atributo src,

utiliza el inspector de elementos para verificar la URL que se genera, y ve si es la correcta. puede que tengas que anteponer un / o ../ en la url. quedando así /imagen/foto1.jpg o ../imagen/foto1.jpg

Comment: Apoyo lo que dice @milo, si pudieras mostrar la estructura de tu proyecto, ya sea con una imagen u una estructura escrita, sera de mucha ayuda a responder tu pregunta.

Comment: Bueno de echo si me muestra las imagenes  una debajo de la otra (todas las imagenes) mi problema esta en como colocarlas dentro del slider para que se muestre una a la vez y no todas juntas

Comment: En ese caso, estás usando alguna librería especifica para el slider?
o tu estás programando el slider desde cero?

Comment: desde cero, estaba usando bootstrap pero me imagino que por las versiones, tengo complicaciones con bootstrap me aparece pero tengo unas modaldes que dejan de funcionar correctamente, por eso es que quiero desarrollarlo propiamente, aunque me esta costando poder solucionarlo, he encontrado slider pero de imagenes fijas o de un arreglo fijo, pero no de una base de datos